# Syncing Tables In Databases - H2 -Springboot - Maven - Flyway - Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, h2, flyway

I am solving a problem that I was given as a challenge and I am on the last step. I am trying to sync two tables inside a database. Anytime an insert, update, or delete occurs in one table, the same should occur in the other table. The github repo is listed below and these are some articles I am looking at to see if this is how this problem can be solved. Also please keep in mind I do not know Java in any way shape or form. I am a junior JavaScript developer so please be thorough in explanation so I may have a better chance of understanding the proposed solution. This is the challenge...

We need to create 2 database tables called Task_definition and Task_definition_mirror. Each table has the following columns: [ID, Name, Description]. ID is a Primary Key. Name can’t be null, Description can.

The users can modify data in any of these tables at any given point of time(i.e. change the value of Name or/and Description, delete rows, insert new rows).

Once any change takes place on any of the tables, the change should be synced to the other table.

The users or/and other applications can modify tables directly (i.e. no web application, just SQL statements are run on DB).

No DB triggers are allowed. The solution should be written in pure Java.

Hint: you can leverage Spring-boot-scheduler features

Requirements:

The solution should work
Clean and readable code
The project should use maven
The project should use Spring Boot
Flyway should manage the creation of table definitions
Tests should be included. Tests should prove your solution works. 
Please use H2 database

Current github repo with my code solution
https://github.com/antdevelopment1/javaChallenge

This is something I think I can use but I am unsure.
http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#clustering

I have completed most of the task and I feel quite confident I implement spring boot scheduler myself but this step syncing these tables is very confusing to me. I need clarity in how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll take a shot at answering this and keep it relatively high level...

1. There's a task scheduler in Spring boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html details here about setting up a project that uses this. I'd start with this.
2. Use the scheduler to run at regular intervals - you decide how long this is but too often and you'll possibly lock the database, too infrequent and the database will be out of sync and require larger updates to remain in sync. I don't know if this is an issue as I don't know if this is a live DB or just practice
3. Once you have the scheduler set up, you only need to figure out the difference between the two datasets. I know there's `UNION` in SQL (records that are the same between two tables - the intersection between two sets), so there exists an equal and opposite operator `EXCEPT`, equivalent https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm example here. Use this to compute the difference between the two tables from which ever side has the most rows.
4. I probably wouldn't use flyway to perform the migration as my understanding of flyway (having spent the last month or two automating some database initialisation scripts for MySql) is that its used to run migrations of the database state from one state to another (adding columns and updating the value to some default, say) rather than for inserting data at regular intervals. Whilst you could produce a `V4__*.sql` work as a one-off migration, you'd need to maintain the version numbering manually which is far from ideal. Instead generate a list of SQL `INSERT` statements to run against whichever DB has the least amount of rows.

As an alternative to step 4. you could run two `left outer joins`. One to identify which rows are present in table 1 but not in table 2 and a second to identify which rows are present in table 2 but not in table 1. I'd start with this as its perhaps simpler to implement given the logic is sequential ... but it will potentially result in a race condition. where you update DB table 1. then a row is inserted to table 1, and then you update table 2 but the additional row is missing.

I noticed in your github repo you have two `@SpringbootApplication` classes... one should be removed. I think I know which one but I'll leave you to figure that out. (Hint:) The one you're left with declares `@Bean` objects, one of which is a `RestTemplate`... Reuse this by `@Inject/@Autowire`'ing it into the constructor of which ever class has a dependency on it. This saves new-ing up multiple instances of the same object.

Hopefully this is of some help. Just reply if you have any questions and I'll get back when I can.